# Does defeating the flagship in the rebel stronghold sector counts to unlock new ships?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Apart from quests most ships can be unlock by defeating the rebel flagship with the previous ship, what happens if I defeat the damaged rebel flagship in the rebel stronghold sector with (for example) the zoltan cruiser? Will I unlock the mantis cruiser or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, the [Flagship Construction](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Federation_Cruiser) does not unlock ships in the same way as beating the finished [Flagship](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Flagship) at the end of the game. They are two different events  (and fights), that do not share the same flags. The flagship construction has it's own explicit event flag, "FLAGSHIP_CONSTRUCTION".

The game most likely ties unlock new ships through beating the game, not from just beating a 3rd phase flagship.

The only ship you will unlock through beating the flagship construction is the [Federation Cruiser](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Federation_Cruiser#Federation_Cruiser).